writing a string out to excel results in a decimal error
I have a program that takes a load of data from sql queries and outputs it to an excel spreadsheet.
myWkBook.Sheets(Row.Item("intTypeSort")).Cells(4, j) = Row.Item("strDescription")

the current variables in the code above are as follows:
J = 2
Row.Item("intTypeSort") = 1
Row.Item("strDescription") = "Missing NiNO (TPR)"

the error that comes up is

HResult=0x80131516   Message=Value was either too large or too small
for a Decimal.

I'm not sure why the error is referring to the value is too large for a decimal when the sql database query is returning a string that is held in a string data field.
the version of excel I have on my machine is version 2406(build17726.20206) from my company's 365 apps for enterprise subscription.
following some suggestions from comments I've implemented the following code changes
Dim intsheetindex As Integer
Dim stroutputitem As String
intsheetindex = Row.Item("intTypeSort")
stroutputitem = Row.Item("strDescription")
myWkBook.Sheets(intsheetindex).Cells(4, j) = stroutputitem

this has not fixed the problem.
variables contain the following:
j = 2
intsheetindex = 1
stroutputitem = "Missing NiNO (TPR)"


What's the value of Row.Item("intTypeSort")

@Rory its 1 but I'm fairly sure theres a sheet with that index number otherwise a previous line of code .Sheets(1).Name = "Common" would also error out

There is always a Sheets(1) :) I was just checking as I can't see any other possibility from that code for that error.

What happens if you type Missing NiNO (TPR) into the cell?

What are the types of j and Row.Item("intTypeSort")?

Try converting them to their actual data types when writing to excel,

@JNevill j is an integer  as defined within the.net source code - int type sort type sort is a int field return by a sql query I suppose I could put an in-between step where I get the retirned value from the sql query and then explictly pass it to a.net defined integer. just to eliminate any type mis match problems.
